# How to close or Handle pop up having 2 buttons(Confirm and Cancel) in Selenium IDE

Tags: popup, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE for a healthcare application, when a Patient is registered in the hospital a pop appears to Print the Patient Details(having confirm and Cancel button on it).
All though I have managed to play the test without closing the pop, but I need to close it for better functioning and presentation.

Comment: Any code will be helpful...

Comment: <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>css=img.button</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForPopUp</td>
 <td>popupWindow</td>
 <td>30000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>selectWindow</td>
 <td>name=popupWindow</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>//img[@onclick='window.close();']</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>